# how to load image in gridview using using qualcomn SNPE SDK?

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, qualcomm

I am follow this link tutorial  [https://developer.qualcomm.com/software/snapdragon-neural-processing-engine-ai/getting-started and i am able to download all model image but my requirement is now i need how to display gallery image in grid view my code is for model overview fragment:

```
public class ModelOverviewFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String EXTRA_MODEL = "model";

enum MenuRuntimeGroup {

    SelectCpuRuntime(NeuralNetwork.Runtime.CPU),
    SelectGpuRuntime(NeuralNetwork.Runtime.GPU),
    SelectDspRuntime(NeuralNetwork.Runtime.DSP);

    public static int ID = 1;

    public NeuralNetwork.Runtime runtime;

    MenuRuntimeGroup(NeuralNetwork.Runtime runtime) {
        this.runtime = runtime;
    }
}

private GridView mImageGrid;

private ModelImagesAdapter mImageGridAdapter;

private ModelOverviewFragmentController mController;

private TextView mDimensionsText;

private TextView mModelNameText;

private Spinner mOutputLayersSpinners;

private TextView mClassificationText;

private TextView mModelVersionText;

public static ModelOverviewFragment create(final Model model) {
    final ModelOverviewFragment fragment = new ModelOverviewFragment();
    final Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putParcelable(EXTRA_MODEL, model);
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_model, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mImageGrid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.model_image_grid);
    mImageGridAdapter = new ModelImagesAdapter(getActivity());
    mImageGrid.setAdapter(mImageGridAdapter);
    mImageGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final Bitmap bitmap = mImageGridAdapter.getItem(position);
            mController.classify(bitmap);
        }
    });

    mModelNameText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.model_overview_name_text);
    mModelVersionText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.model_overview_version_text);
    mDimensionsText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.model_overview_dimensions_text);
    mOutputLayersSpinners = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.model_overview_layers_spinner);
    mClassificationText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.model_overview_classification_text);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    final Model model = getArguments().getParcelable(EXTRA_MODEL);
    mController = new ModelOverviewFragmentController(
            (Application) getActivity().getApplicationContext(), model);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    final SNPE.NeuralNetworkBuilder builder = new SNPE.NeuralNetworkBuilder(
            (Application) (getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
    for (MenuRuntimeGroup item : MenuRuntimeGroup.values()) {
        if (builder.isRuntimeSupported(item.runtime)) {
            menu.add(MenuRuntimeGroup.ID, item.ordinal(), 0, item.runtime.name());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getGroupId() == MenuRuntimeGroup.ID) {
        final MenuRuntimeGroup option = MenuRuntimeGroup.values()[item.getItemId()];
        mController.setTargetRuntime(option.runtime);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mController.attach(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    mController.detach(this);
    super.onStop();
}

public void addSampleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (mImageGridAdapter.getPosition(bitmap) == -1) {
        mImageGridAdapter.add(bitmap);
        mImageGridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public void setNetworkDimensions(Map<String, int[]> inputDimensions) {
    mDimensionsText.setText(Arrays.toString(inputDimensions.get("data")));
}

public void displayModelLoadFailed() {
    mClassificationText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mClassificationText.setText(R.string.model_load_failed);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.model_load_failed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void setModelName(String modelName) {
    mModelNameText.setText(modelName);
}

public void setModelVersion(String version) {
    mModelVersionText.setText(version);
}

public void setOutputLayersNames(Set<String> outputLayersNames) {
    mOutputLayersSpinners.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(
        getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        new LinkedList<>(outputLayersNames)));
}

public void setClassificationResult(String[] classificationResult) {
    if (classificationResult.length > 0) {
        mClassificationText.setText(
                String.format("%s: %s", classificationResult[0], classificationResult[1]));
    }
    mClassificationText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void setLoadingVisible(boolean visible) {
    mClassificationText.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    if (visible) {
        mClassificationText.setText(R.string.loading_network);
    }
}

public void displayModelNotLoaded() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.model_not_loaded, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void displayClassificationFailed() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.classification_failed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private static class ModelImagesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Bitmap> {

    public ModelImagesAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.model_image_layout);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.model_image_layout, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        final ImageView imageView = ImageView.class.cast(view);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(getItem(position));
        return view;
    }
}
```

}
for image loading code :

```
public class LoadImageTask extends AsyncTask<File, Void, Bitmap> {

private final ModelOverviewFragmentController mController;

private final File mImageFile;

public LoadImageTask(ModelOverviewFragmentController controller, final File imageFile) {
    mController = controller;
    mImageFile = imageFile;
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(File... params) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImageFile.getAbsolutePath());
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
    mController.onBitmapLoaded(mImageFile, bitmap);
}
```

}

/*public class LoadImageTask extends AsyncTask{

```
private final ModelOverviewFragmentController mController;
private File path;



public LoadImageTask(ModelOverviewFragmentController controller, File jpeg)
{
    mController=controller;
    path=jpeg;
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    File file = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + path);


    if(file.exists()){
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        Log.d("ImagePath",bitmap.toString());
    }

    return bitmap;

}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    mController.onBitmapLoaded(path,result);
}
```

}
for model :

```
public class Model implements Parcelable {

public static final Uri MODELS_URI = Uri.parse("content://snpe/models");
```

// public static final  Uri MODELS_URI=Uri.parse("content://mtp://[usb:002,029]/Internal%20shared%20storage/DCIM");

```
public static final String INVALID_ID = "null";

public File file;
public String[] labels;
public File[] rawImages;
public File[] jpgImages;
public String name;
public File meanImage;

protected Model(Parcel in) {
    name = in.readString();
    file = new File(in.readString());

    final String[] rawPaths = new String[in.readInt()];
    in.readStringArray(rawPaths);
    rawImages = fromPaths(rawPaths);

    final String[] jpgPaths = new String[in.readInt()];
    in.readStringArray(jpgPaths);
    jpgImages = fromPaths(jpgPaths);

    meanImage = new File(in.readString());

    labels = new String[in.readInt()];
    in.readStringArray(labels);
}

public Model() {}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeString(file.getAbsolutePath());
    dest.writeInt(rawImages.length);
    dest.writeStringArray(toPaths(rawImages));
    dest.writeInt(jpgImages.length);
    dest.writeStringArray(toPaths(jpgImages));
    dest.writeString(meanImage.getAbsolutePath());
    dest.writeInt(labels.length);
    dest.writeStringArray(labels);
}

private File[] fromPaths(String[] paths) {
    final File[] files = new File[paths.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
        files[i] = new File(paths[i]);
    }
    return files;
}

private String[] toPaths(File[] files) {
    final String[] paths = new String[files.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        paths[i] = files[i].getAbsolutePath();
    }
    return paths;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public static final Creator<Model> CREATOR = new Creator<Model>() {
    @Override
    public Model createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Model(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Model[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Model[size];
    }
};

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name.toUpperCase();
}
```

}

Comment: any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

To load SD card images in grid view, please make few changes in loadImageSamples method of ModelOverviewFragmentController.java. Currently, the images are picked from snpe folder inside internal storage of the device and are populated on Grid View. To get all the images from the gallery, create AsyncTask class to load images from the Gallery to the Grid View with the help of Content Provider.
Please use this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/10877404 for code reference to load images on grid view.

Hope this helps!

Thank You